is it possible for one put endpoint to have a param that have more than 1 type on fastapi, pydantic
so first of full, the goal of this question is to gain more knowledge about if it possible, and what is the pest practice.
there are 3 types of users
7, 6 are normal users
5,4 are publishers
3,2 are managers
1 is admin
i use this function to dedicate user_role
and here is the first question
i will use this function alot and i think about it,
i can just add user_role to JWT token, but i think it gonna make a security issue, is that right?
async def check_permission(
    permission: int,
    current_user: user_dependecny,
    db: db_dependecny,
    error: bool = True,
):
    current_user_role = (
        db.query(user.User).filter(user.User.id == current_user.id).first().user_role
    )
    # 7= reader, 6= Pro_reader,
    # 5= publisher, 4= editor,
    # 3= small_manager, 2= big_manager, 1= admin
    if current_user_role <= permission:
        return True
    elif error == False:
        return False
    elif current_user_role > permission:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN, detail="Do not have premisson."
        )

to the main question on title
trying to use many data_type on one param is possible by using Union
from typing import Annotated, Union, cast
type1 = None
type2 = None
type3 = None
var: Union[type1,type2,type3]

first time i tried it with get enpoint on model_response and it worked.
what code below is doing is returning user data based on your user_role and to do that i needed 3 deferent basemodels
@router.get(
    "/{user_id}/", response_model=Union[SelfUserInfo, ManagerUserInfo, UserInfo]
)
async def read_user(
    user_id: int,
    db: db_dependecny,
    current_user: user_dependecny,
):
    db_user = db.query(user.User).filter(user.User.id == user_id).first()
    if db_user is None:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND, detail="user is not found"
        )
    if await check_permission(3, current_user, db, error=False) == True:
        user_data = ManagerUserInfo(
            username=db_user.username,
            avatar_url=db_user.avatar_url,
            user_role=db_user.user_role,
            email=db_user.email,
            country_id=db_user.country_id,
            last_login=db_user.last_login,
            date_joined=db_user.date_joined,
            is_verfied=db_user.is_verfied,
            state=db_user.state,
            is_staff=db_user.is_staff,
            is_superuser=db_user.is_superuser,
        )
        return user_data
    else:
        if current_user.id == user_id:
            user_data = SelfUserInfo(
                username=db_user.username,
                avatar_url=db_user.avatar_url,
                user_role=db_user.user_role,
                email=db_user.email,
                country_id=db_user.country_id,
                last_login=db_user.last_login,
                date_joined=db_user.date_joined,
                is_verfied=db_user.is_verfied,
            )
            return user_data
        else:
            user_data = UserInfo(
                username=db_user.username,
                avatar_url=db_user.avatar_url,
                user_role=db_user.user_role,
            )
        return user_data

my second question about this code is it not following pest practice.
last code were i have a problem
my problem is user_data type always SelfUserUpdate
specifically first type on
user_data: Union[SelfUserUpdate, ManagerUserUpdate, AdminUserUpdate], 

how to fix it and is it okey and not a ba practice to do it like that instead of
making 3 deferent endpoints.
@router.put("/{user_id}/")
async def Update_user(
    user_id: int,
    current_user: user_dependecny,
    db: db_dependecny,
    user_data: Union[SelfUserUpdate, ManagerUserUpdate, AdminUserUpdate],
):
    db_user = db.query(user.User).filter(user.User.id == user_id).first()
    if db_user is None:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND, detail="user is not found"
        )
    if await check_permission(1, current_user, db, error=False) == True:
        # Admin edit user
        db_user.username = user_data.username
        db_user.avatar_url = user_data.avatar_url
        db_user.email = user_data.email
        db_user.country_id = user_data.country_id
        db_user.user_role = user_data.user_role
        db_user.state = user_data.state
        db_user.is_staff = user_data.is_staff
        db_user.is_verfied = user_data.is_verfied
        db_user.is_superuser = user_data.is_superuser
        db.commit()
        db.refresh(db_user)
        return user_data

    elif check_permission(3, current_user, db, error=False) == True:
        # Manager edit user
        db_user.username = user_data.username
        db_user.avatar_url = user_data.avatar_url
        db_user.email = user_data.email
        db_user.country_id = user_data.country_id
        db_user.user_role = user_data.user_role
        db_user.state = user_data.state
        db_user.is_staff = user_data.is_staff
        db.commit()
        db.refresh(db_user)
        return user_data
    elif current_user.id == user_id:
        # current user edit him self
        db_user.username = user_data.username
        db_user.avatar_url = user_data.avatar_url
        db_user.email = user_data.email
        db_user.country_id = user_data.country_id
        db.commit()
        db.refresh(db_user)
        return user_data
    else:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST,
            detail="You can't change This user.",
        )


Seems like there is a mistake in the title. The question is about the return type of the endpoint, but not about the param of the endpoint, isn't it?

@YuriiMotov it is the param on put endpoint , look at last code

Oh, I see. Anyway, you need either to specify union's order or use discriminated union

i found out a way to do it on more simplest way
first, i need to edit schema and use nested models.
from pydantic.json_schema import SkipJsonSchema

class AdminUserUpdate(BaseModel):
    is_verfied: bool
    is_superuser: bool


class ManagerUserUpdate(BaseModel):
    user_role: int
    state: UserState
    is_staff: bool


class UserUpdate(BaseModel):
    username: str
    avatar_url: Optional[str] = None
    email: EmailStr
    country_id: int
    Manager_data: SkipJsonSchema[ManagerUserUpdate] = None
    Admin_data: SkipJsonSchema[AdminUserUpdate] = None

using SkipJsonSchema will make them not appear on the schema on openapi, but still i can write it by my self.
also, when i get a response Manager_data, Admin_data will shown as null if you didn't add them so it is okey if they shown up.
last of the code is the endpoint.
@router.put("/{user_id}/")
async def Update_user(
    user_id: int,
    current_user: user_dependecny,
    db: db_dependecny,
    user_data: UserUpdate,
):
    db_user = db.query(user.User).filter(user.User.id == user_id).first()
    if db_user is None:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND, detail="user is not found"
        )

    username_search = (
        db.query(user.User).filter(user.User.username == user_data.username).first()
    )
    if (
        username_search.username == user_data.username
        and username_search.id != db_user.id
    ):
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_409_CONFLICT,
            detail="Username is already exist.",
        )
    else:
        db_user.username = user_data.username

    email_search = (
        db.query(user.User).filter(user.User.email == user_data.email).first()
    )
    if email_search.email == user_data.email and email_search.id != db_user.id:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_409_CONFLICT, detail="Email is already exist."
        )
    else:
        db_user.email = user_data.email

    db_user.avatar_url = user_data.avatar_url
    db_user.country_id = user_data.country_id

    if await check_permission(1, current_user, db, error=False) == True:
        # Admin edit user
        db_user.user_role = user_data.Manager_data.user_role
        db_user.state = user_data.Manager_data.state
        db_user.is_staff = user_data.Manager_data.is_staff
        db_user.is_verfied = user_data.Admin_data.is_verfied
        db_user.is_superuser = user_data.Admin_data.is_superuser
        db.commit()
        db.refresh(db_user)
        return user_data

    elif await check_permission(3, current_user, db, error=False) == True:
        db_user.user_role = user_data.Manager_data.user_role
        db_user.state = user_data.Manager_data.state
        db_user.is_staff = user_data.Manager_data.is_staff
        db.commit()
        db.refresh(db_user)
        return user_data
    elif current_user.id == user_id:
        db.commit()
        db.refresh(db_user)
        return user_data
    else:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST,
            detail="You can't edit This user.",
        )

